# What does %*c do when getting input from stdin?

Tags: c, pointers, input, stdin, format-specifiers

I know what it does, and it is a format specifier.
but I have no clue on how this works.
It gets the last input, and just doesn't save it.
But how?

Comment: did you read the documentation?

Comment: You can always read the [source code for implementation details](https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.22/scanf_8c_source.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting asterisk indicates that the data is to be read from the stream but ignored (i.e. it is not stored in the location pointed by an argument).
Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

So the data would not be saved in the variable.

Comment: [cplusplus](http://cplusplus.com) has been proven incompetent by the content it provides, it's advised to use [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) instead.